# Is there a battery with smaller cells inside of it?

Tags: batteries

I vaguely recall reading a place that a simple way to get small battery cells is to open a battery which contained 5-6 of these. I thought it was an AA battery, but I've been Googling, and have found that they don't seem to contain anything of the sort. So I'm wondering, am I just making up things, or is there a battery that suits my description?

Comment: Do keep in mind that while the batteries themselves are relatively safe to handle, the cells inside may not be - chemical leakage, potting material, sticky fillers, and crumbling carbon on fingers come to mind from personal past explorations down the path you are considering!

Comment: https://i.reddit.com/r/mildlyinteresting/comments/50lyvp/my_battery_was_made_up_of_smaller_batteries/  

Also

https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.1vC8DKNv8FzE8XGARuby7QHaHQ?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A 9 V battery might be made up of 6 type AAAA 1.5 V cells in series:

[image]

(Image from [here](http://staspika.wordpress.com/2009/06/15/9v-battery-inside/))

As you can see in the [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/9V_innards_3_different_cells.jpg/320px-9V_innards_3_different_cells.jpg) provided by Anindo, not all 9 V batteries are made this way.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine-volt_battery), more 9 volt battery interiors, some with a different configuration of small cells: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ea/9V_innards_3_different_cells.jpg/320px-9V_innards_3_different_cells.jpg

Comment: There are also 4.5 V batteries with 3 1.5 V cells inside. Unfortunately, I can't remember their designation at the moment.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Lantern Batteries. 3R12, 3LR12.